# Does this kind of attention exist?

Tags: attention

As someone who is new to deep learning, I am only familiar with self-attention.

I'm designing a model. Imagine there are n data, which the $i_{th}$ data can be represented as a vector $x_i$. And the data has an attribute $a$, the attribute of the $i_{th}$ data is $a_i$. now I only use one query vector $q$ to multiply each data to calculate the result as the weight $w_i$ ($w_i=q^t x_i$) , and use the weight of each data to multiply each data's attribute $a_i$ as the final result. ($A=\sum w_i a_i$)
Does this kind of attention exist? if so what its name is?

For example, $x_i$ is a 768-dimensional vector representing each sentence, and $s_i$ is a 3-dimensional vector representing each sentence's sentiment. $q$ is a 768-dimensional vector multiplied with each $x_i$ to produce each sentence's weight $w_i$. And the weighted sum $S=\sum w_i s_i$ is the overall sentiment of all sentences.

Comment: I think this description needs a bit more clarity. Here are the things I don't yet get: 1) Is $*$ the dot- or the elementwise product? 2) You first have $A = \sum w_i * a_i$, where $a_i$ denote attributes (i.e. vector dimensions), but in the bottom you have $S = \sum w_i s_i$ where of $s_i$ you have 3 and of $a_i$ you have 768, so $A$ and $S$ are not the same thing, right? 3) Is the $\sum$ taken over attributes $i$? In that case you will get per-sentence sentiment and not overall sentiment of all sentences, right?

Comment: @Chillston no it simply means matrix multiplication, $q^t$ is a 1*768 dimensional matrix (a row vector) and $x_i$ is a 768*1 matrix (a column vector), so $w_i$ is a scalar. $s_i$ is $a_i$ and $S$ is $A$ described above, because it is sentiment score so I used the letter s. I never said $a_i$ is 768-dimensional, it is $x_i$ with 768 dimensions. For example, there are n sentences, the $i_{th}$ sentence can be vectorized as $x_i$, $s_i$ is the sentiment 3-dimensional vector of this sentence, which represents [positive probability, neutral probability, negative probability]

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. Ah so you are not trying to do sentiment analysis, but use the sentiment as additional input to your model?

Comment: @Chillston it is not taken over attributes $i$, it is taken over the whole dataset (the sentences set), and $i$ means the $i_{th}$ sentence. imagine it is an article or something like it. $w_i$ is the weight I give to the $i_{th}$ sentence and $s_i$ is the $i_{th}$ sentence's sentiment vector. there is only one attribute which is the sentiment vector of each sentence, and $W = \sum w_i s_i$ is the sum over all sentences' sentiment and yes it is 3-dimensional as well.

Comment: @Chillston yes I simply used pretrained-bert models to produce the sentiment vector for each sentence.

Comment: Okay, I get now how you create the attention weights $w_i$, but the $A = \sum w_ia_i$ is a sum over the whole dataset? Isn't it rather the sum over the input sentences to the model?

Comment: @Chillston  yes by whole dataset I mean all the inputs. for example there are n news headlines, it is all fed into this model to calculate weight for each headline. So it is the weighted sum over all headlines. it is later fed into a larger model as input.

Comment: Sorry, I really try to understand this: Given an input $X$ to your model. Then $X$ are a number of sentences and $X$ is a subset of your full dataset $D$, right? Is the sum computed over $X$ or over $D$?

Comment: @Chillston For example, there are 10 days' data, each day has 50 news. I calculated a weighted sum of each day's sentiment,  so each day's weighted sentiment is calculated using this day's 50 news. and there are 10 3-dimensional vectors because there are 10 days. and I put it into a RNN or something. I really dont know what makes the confusion. the whole aim is to train the query vector q. you dont have to understand my model, it is just an example. I just want to know if there is already any kind of attention like this. is it naive attention? plain attention or something like this?

Comment: Probably what causes my confusion is that, effectively, your attention for the $i-th$ element is independent of the other elements in the sentence, right? I am thinking that inside a GRU/LSTM you have the update gates that seem to be a more expressive version of what you are doing, but I could be wrong. To answer your question: I don't know of any paper that proposes something like this, but something like the update-gates in RNNs or the [gated activation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05941v1) seems be very related.

Comment: I found my idea quite similar to this picture https://pic4.zhimg.com/v2-a5b5df8902420bb10688fcf6ed1dc38d_r.jpg?source=1940ef5c, where $q$ is the query, $k_i$ is the key vector of the $i_{th}$ data and $v_i$ is the value vector of the $i_{th}$ data. But I still can't find which paper it comes from.

Comment: It looks pretty silimar, do you have a link to a paper or something where that figure is from?

Comment: @Chillston https://www.zhihu.com/question/68482809/answer/1876764572 It is written in chinese though. It is not from the first paper in his reference. Sukhbaatar, Sainbayar, et al. "End-to-end memory networks." arXiv preprint arXiv:1503.08895 (2015) so I don't know where it is from.